# Google Charts: passing dates without using Date()?

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

**Summary**

I'm trying to make a line graph in Google Charts with dates as the X axis. I have that all sorted but it requires passing dates as `Date` objects, i.e. `new Date(2005, 3, 13)`. Is there any way I can pass it as a Unix timestamp or perhaps a string instead?

**More Details**

So I have a bunch of data in PHP that I want to graph. I'm taking the data and arranging it into an array in the format that will produce the correct JSON format when run through `json_encode()`, per [the Google data docs](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews.html#javascriptliteral):

```
$graph_data = array(
    'cols' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'date',
            'label' => 'Date',
            'type' => 'datetime',
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'odometer',
            'label' => 'Miles',
            'type' => 'number',
        ),
    ),
    'rows' => array(
        array(
            'c' => array(
                array( 'v' => 1331479502 ),
                array( 'v' => 56872 ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'c' => array(
                array( 'v' => 1331375984 ),
                array( 'v' => 55324 ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'c' => array(
                array( 'v' => 1328966460 ),
                array( 'v' => 54244 ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

`{"cols":[{"id":"date","label":"Date","type":"datetime"},{"id":"odometer","label":"Miles","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":1331479502},{"v":56872}]},{"c":[{"v":1331375984},{"v":55324}]},{"c":[{"v":1328966460},{"v":54244}]}]}`

So I have the JSON creation down but the API wants dates passed as a `Date` object and not a number (or string). It throws an error right now but if I change it from `datetime` to `number`, it graphs perfectly so I know my JSON format is correct.

Is there anything I can do to have the API accept Unix timestamps, or perhaps a string of some sort?

As I typed this out, I realized that perhaps I could use some Javascript to walk the JSON object and replace the timestamps with `Date` objects, but it'd be nice if I didn't have to do any data manipulation via Javascript.

**EDIT**

I got part of the way there by setting the `type` to `number` and passing dates like this:

```
        array(
            'c' => array(
                array( 'v' => 1331479502, 'f' => 'March 11th, 2012' ),
                array( 'v' => 56872 ),
            ),
        ),
```

That makes the `f` value show up in the tooltip (yay!) but the `v` value is still used for the axis labels. Hmm.

**EDIT #2**

Looks like there might be some potential in using [DataView](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes.html#Help) to transform a `number` timestamp into a date but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up just walking the JSON array and replacing the timestamps with `Date` objects. It was easier than I expected it to be:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < json.rows.length; i++ ) { 
    json.rows[i].c[0].v = new Date( json.rows[i].c[0].v * 1000 );
}
```

Comment: Where you did this loop? Thanks!

Comment: @Moozy: Within the Javascript in order to pre-process the data. You can see a demo in the source of http://www.viper007bond.com/about/my-cars/. I've also mirrored it here as a backup incase my site ever changes in the future: http://pastebin.com/xsQm8qZT

Answer (score 0):

I used string instead of date type when displayed Date on x-axis. 
It allowed me to customize DateTime display on server side by formatting it as a string and also there is no need in tricks like creating date object from some string or a numeric values in javascript.

Comment: Thanks but the issue with using `string` is that makes for a [discrete](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes.html#Discrete_vs_Continuous) axis rather than a continuous axis, i.e. data points are evenly spaced out rather than being spread out based on the actual value.